# Wireguard VPN not working with VNC

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop

NOTE: I originally asked this on SuperUser and so far no response-- since I am running on Mac, maybe the Apple community will have an idea.

After many trials, I have gotten my Wireguard VPN to largely work to allow outside access to our local net, but something is still not quite right as VNC/screen sharing will not connect

The setup: We have a static IP from our ISP, which works fine for inbound/outbound. Local net is a 192.168/19, Peers on both ends are macOS. Wireguard onsite peer is set up to use 10.x.x.x/24. I originally followed [these instructions](https://barrowclift.me/post/wireguard-server-on-macos) recently, to simplify testing, I am just using the Wireguard app and manually adding the route using `pfctl`:

`nat on en0 from 10.x.x./24 to 192.168/19 -> (en0)`

What Works:

- Connection establishes, Data flow meters on outside peer show data being sent and received.
- Ping to any machine on the internal networks.
  ssh works
- FileMaker server on internal net access works
- Traceroute SORT OF works: this may be key: prints 3 asterisks, with a delay of about 10 seconds, then finally shows target machine followed by delay and another asterisk. When I connect via our regular VPN (`vpnd`), `traceroute` runs immediately and shows a single hop to the target

What doesn't work:

- Screen Sharing / VNC: brings up a dialog box to authenticate; after hitting OK, spins for about a minute and reports failure.

I don't think there is a problem with our basic network setup since our old VPN server (macOS built-in `vpnd`, running on a different machine and external public IP but same localnet) works fine. I am stumped.